# Contenido ViewPager se borra al salir del fragmen y regresar con el boton atras

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager

Tengo varios fragments los cuales tiene varios tabs, el problema esta en que al cambiar de fragmen y regresar precionado el boton atras del  navigation bar, el contenido no aparece, solo aparece la barra con los titulos de las tabs.

Este es mi adaptador de las tabas.

```
private List<Fragment> fragments;
private List<String> titulos;


public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
{
    super(fm);
    fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    titulos = new ArrayList<>();
}



public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String titulo)
{
    fragments.add(fragment);
    titulos.add(titulo);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
{
    return titulos.get(position);
}
```

}

y asi es como le envio los datos a traves del adaptador.

```
    appBar = parent.findViewById(R.id.appBar);

    tabs = new TabLayout(getContext());
    tabs.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    appBar.addView(tabs);
    viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(ArticuloFragment.getInstance("Teléfonos", getConsulta("Teléfonos"), usuarioId, permiso, idPVenta, puntoVenta), "Teléfonos");
    adapter.addFragment(ArticuloFragment.getInstance("Chips", getConsulta("Chips"), usuarioId, permiso, idPVenta, puntoVenta), "Chips");
    adapter.addFragment(ArticuloFragment.getInstance("Accesorios", getConsulta("Accesorios"), usuarioId, permiso, idPVenta, puntoVenta), "Accesorios");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabs.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Nota: Este error solo susede con los fragments que contiene tabs los demas no perden su contenido al regresar con el boton atras del navigation bar.
Me base en este ejemplo para hacerlo http://www.proyectosimio.com/es/programacion-android-como-usar-fragments-con-viewpager-y-efecto-swipe/

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo algo raro con tu adapter. De hecho, es la primera vez que veo un adapter de tabs de esta manera. La solucion inmediata que te puedo dar es implemetarlo de otra forma, la cual considero correcta y es la que siempre uso.

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public List<Fragment> mFragments;
    public List<String> titulos;


    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.mFragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
{
    return titulos.get(position);
}
```

Arma la lista de fragments en tu activity y pasala ya armada. Es una mejor practica Y usa el FragmentStatePagerAdapter para que te ayude con el control de los fragments en pantalla. Mucha suerte.